# Marshal C# struct into a byte[]

Tags: c#, marshalling

Is there a way to serialize a C# structure, annotated with `[StructLayout]`, into a **managed** byte array, i. e. a `byte[]`, either premade or with allocation?

I can see marshaling to unmanaged memory then copying, but that's ugly.

Comment: The 99% usecase is for dealing with unmanaged APIs, may I ask why you want to use marshalling to obtain the byte array, as opposed to some form of serialization?

Comment: Marshal.StructureToPtr() requires a pointer, no demand that this is a pointer to unmanaged memory.  Use the *fixed* keyword (fastest) or GCHandle.Alloc+AddrOfPinnedObject

Comment: fixed structure layout is a form of serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout `MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>()`.  It will easily allow you to change from byte/short/int/long arrays to Structures and back.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences mixing managed and unmanaged data is all about clearly defining the transition from one space to another.

When i have had the requirement of going from native to managed or the other way the first step has always been to copy data to the 'target' space and then forward that.

I assume that you are already familiar with the interop services since you mentioned copying and `[StructLayout]`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure_System_IntPtr_System_Object_

If you find a better way please do tell